# After limiting the access to my wp-login.php by IP through .htaccess, all my password-protected posts stopped working. What's the best solution now?

Tags: security, password, wp-login-form

To avoid brute force and illegal access to my WordPress website, I've limited the access to the *wp-login.php* script by IP addresses, using the .htaccess file. In other words, only certain IPs can access this php file to attempt a login to my WordPress site. So far so good, but now I've noticed that *all* my password-protected posts are not working anymore, and I need to ask the customer's IP address to include in the .htaccess file for wp-login.php so that they are able to use the post password to access the post. It is like the password-protection feature of a post needs wp-login.php to be authenticated.

**Is there a workaround for that?** I still need to protect wp-login.php against illegal access to my WordPress admin console, but I do not want to limit by IP the access to password-protected posts

Below my .htaccess file:

```
#turn on url rewriting
RewriteEngine on
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

<Files wp-login.php>
  order deny,allow
  allow from 99.199.199.1
  allow from 99.199.199.2
  allow from 99.199.199.3
  allow from 99.199.199.4
  deny from all
</Files>

#remove the need for .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/$3
```

Below the password configuration for a post:

[image: Password Configuration for a Post]

Thanks!

Comment: The password form for protected posts is submitted to wp-login.php, which handles it. So if the user cannot access wp-login.php then they cannot unlock password protected posts.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That's what I've noticed. So what do I do now? I still need to protect wp-login.php against illegal access to my WordPress admin console, but I do not want to limit by IP the access to password-protected posts.

Comment: Besides the obvious answer of removing the IP address filtering?  Instead of only allowing specific IPs access, focus on the actual problem of limiting failed logins.  After 3 failed login attempts in less than a minute you probably have a bad actor to deal with.  https://wordpress.org/support/article/brute-force-attacks/